# Nakama's AddFriend function doesn't work in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nakama

I am trying to use Nakama to add social functions to my game. When I try to send the friend request, I get the "Failed to add friend" error. This is my code:

```
var message = NFriendAddMessage.ById(UserID);
    _client.Send(message, (bool done) => {
        Debug.Log("Friend added or request sent.");
    }, (INError err) => {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("Error: code '{0}' with '{1}'.", err.Code, err.Message);
    }
                );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well let's start with what troubleshooting you have done?  I see you get a "failed to add friend" error, but have you looked into that error to see if anyone else is getting it and what they did to fix it?

Comment: @Eddge Thanks for your comment. I've tried everything! The problem is Nakama is kinda a new thing and not the most popular thing out there. It's hard to google your problems out!

Comment: Have you tried asking on their website?  They have a support chat there.  If it is a new thing, that may be the best place to start if you are having problems with their tool.

Comment: @EddgeI did and they replied. Evidently it is a problem in their server! We know what to do now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is resolved in the 2.0 releases of the server as well as [many new features](https://blog.heroiclabs.com/nakama-2-0-scale-for-millions-of-concurrent-players-88c5cd075936). Definitely give it a go and drop into the [Gitter community](https://gitter.im/heroiclabs/nakama) if you have any questions.